# .NET Core Angular 7 SPA VSTS Deploy

Tags: angular, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, angular7

I'm in the midst of experimenting CI/CD for .NET Core SPA template with Angular on Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS). I run into a problem where upon deploy, ClientApp folder turns into wwwroot, stored within Azure Web App's wwwroot. That means now I have 2 wwwroots.

Also, because of the messed up folders, the following chunk no longer works.

```
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
```

It's simple to set it up. Just create a new Web Application project with Visual Studio, select Angular. Then run `ng update` to move all the way to Angular 7. An `angular.json` file should be generated for you in the process.

[image]

I tried many things, but none of them helped.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. I added Conditions to .csproj but forgot to include Environment / Build Variables. It was causing npm to not run. Bummer.